What does "these guys" refer to?
In Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse (2018), after he has finished activating a device capable of breaching parallel realities, Kingpin  commands his scientist, while Miles watches him from afar under the rubble:

KINGPIN: Get that thing ready to go again. And soon. Run faster! These guys are weak.

What does "these guys" refer to?

does anyone else feel like all these questions are from an AI? like, they're obvious if you watched the movie, but to teach an AI to disambiguate maybe they'd make sense?

@Alexia not from an AI, but from someone with serious comprehension problems. Someone else is arguing "English as a second language", but it doesn't fit in my opinion, because the user is capable of phrasing questions and providing context in articulate English (complete with idioms). I think it's someone trying to offload their thinking processes to scifi.stackexchange, asking questions about every single turn of phrase in the Spiderverse movies. Not exactly off-topic, but a bit puzzling (if this is an AI bot, I think it should be banned).

@AndresF. I am not a bot.

@HaoLano To be clear, I don't think you are. I'm just curious about your questions, which are somewhat odd (but are not off-topic!).


but are not off-topic!

Then its alright.

He's referring to the scientist types that he hired to help him create his whizzy new superdimensional supercolliding supercollider. You see one of them fleeing when they realise that Kingpin is going to set it off again, having nearly destroyed the city on its first test.
Kingpin remarks, to Tombstone, that they're pretty weak-willed if they're going to run away at the first sign of trouble.

KINGPIN: Tombstone. We’re done with tests. Get that thing ready to go again.
The scientist BACKS AWAY, runs. Kingpin shakes his head.
KINGPIN (CONT’D): Run faster. These guys are weak.
Spider-man: Into the Spider-Verse Screenplay


